# Laravel Eloquent Self Join Parent Child

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, self-join

## Laravel Eloquent Self Join Parent Child Relationship

```
class Product_category extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table='PRODUCT_CATEGORIES';
    public $timestamps = false;


    public function getParentCategory() {
        return $this->hasOne(self::class, 'id', 'parent_id');
    }.


    public function getChildCategories(){
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id','id');
    }
```

I am able to retrieve all child records of table by making use of getChildeCategories but not able to retrieve Parent of particular category.
It always gives me null.

Answer (score 3):

It's called one-to-many relationship, the inverse of a `hasMany` relationship is `belongsTo` method, your `getParentCategory()` should be:

```
public function getParentCategory() {
    return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function getChildCategories(){
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response but it is not showing me appropriate response its giving me same record as i have given, not showing parent id record

Comment: Make sure you check on a child category, also check your database records is `parent_id` filled correctly?

Comment: Child category is working correctly but parent category does not retrieve correct response

Comment: Hmmm.. That's odd, I noticed from your question that you put two variable `(self::class, 'id', 'parent_id')` please make it exactly what you see in my answer

Comment: i have changed the function with exactly what you have specified, i want to retrieve:  suppose if particular row has parent_id as 1 then it should  give me record of id 1, that is why i have use two variables here. Is it wrong way to do?

Comment: First parameter is the model class name, the second parameter is for the foreign key of that model in your case it is `parent_id` , the third parameter is for other key: it's a column name of the value to be added as `parent_id` value on your database row, default is `id` you don't need to specify it unless you don't have `id` column.

Comment: It's also applied to `hasMany()`, except that the third parameter called local key, default value is the same: `id`.

Comment: Just wondering, what code you're using to access the parent and child category?

Comment: If you want learn more how to define one-to-many relationship, please read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback.. yes you were right. code is working properly now.

Comment: Nice! Glad to hear that :)